# How can I find out which version of Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) my server is running?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis, version

My server is running with Windows Server 2003 SP2. How can I check for which version of IIS it is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run a simple asp script on your IIS server:

```
response.write(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_SOFTWARE"))
```

Or look for ASP.DLL (under system32, I believe) right click it, choose properties and check the file version.

However on Windows Server 2003, you are almost certainly running IIS 6.0

Answer (score 4):

**[How do I determine which version of IIS / ASP I'm running?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-determine-which-version-of-iis/asp-i-m-running.html)**

> If you are running Windows Server
>   2003, you are running IIS 6.0 / ASP
>   3.0

OR

1. Do a search for ASP.DLL on your system
2. right-click it and select Properties
3. Check the version tab:

   ```
       IIS 3.0 shows 1.x 
       IIS 4.0 shows 2.x 
       IIS 5.0 shows 5.0.2195.x 
       IIS 5.1 shows 5.1.2600.x 
       IIS 6.0 shows 6.0.3790.x
   ```

Comment: This DLL is most likely in C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\

Comment: There is no `asp.dll` in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv (server 2012 here).

Comment: Look like from IIS 7.0 onward there is no ASP.DLL.